# Accessing json request data in cakephp

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am receiving following Payload from Gitlab.

```
{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "before": "95790bf891e76fee5e1747ab589903a6a1f80f22",
  "after": "da1560886d4f094c3e6c9ef40349f7d38b5d27d7",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "user_id": 4,
  "user_name": "John Smith",
  "user_email": "john@example.com",
  "project_id": 15,
  "repository": {
    "name": "Diaspora",
    "url": "git@example.com:mike/diasporadiaspora.git",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "http://example.com/mike/diaspora", 
    "git_http_url":"http://example.com/mike/diaspora.git",
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:mike/diaspora.git",
    "visibility_level":0
  },
  "total_commits_count": 4
}
```

And in my cakephp function, I am accessing it like this:

```
   public function push() {
          $data = $this->request->data;
          $branch = $data['ref'];
          $gitSshUrl = $data['repository']['git_ssh_url'];
   }
```

I'm successfully able to fetch 'ref' field, but not the repository.git_ssh_url field.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($data);` to see if it is a nested array or perhaps an array with objects?

Comment: No. If its array with objects, then how can I access the ['repository']['git_ssh_url'] ?

Answer (score 0):

The payload you received is a JSON (Check using [this](http://jsonlint.com/)).

You need [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode a JSON string .

```
public function push() {
   $data = $this->request->data('Post.title');
   $data_array = json_decode($data,true);
   $branch = $data_array['ref'];
   $gitSshUrl = $data_array['repository']['git_ssh_url'];
}
```

With Cake you can also do something like

```
$data = $this->request->input('json_decode');    
// Gets JSON encoded data submitted to a PUT/POST action
```

Comment: solved the problem, actually it was gitlab version issue. There was no 'git_ssh_url' in the version I used